# WordPress: Redirect each page/post to subdomain

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, subdirectory

I've a domain let's say `www.example.com` and I created a subdomain as `blog.example.com`     which is actully a subdirectory to my domain `www.example.com/blog`.

Subdomain is working fine for the index file. But when I choose to go to post on my blog it goes to

`www.example.com/blog/first_post`

while I actually want it to look as

`blog.example.com/first_post`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to General Setting

Change Wordpress adress and site adresss URL

From http://www.example.com/blog
TO   http://blog.example.com

It will work